# GUI Wallet History Intact but Zero Balance?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, balance

I'm encountering a new problem with the GUI wallet. I have not yet gone through the process of trying to restore the wallet from seed and hope I don't have to. At one point today, I looked at my wallet which should have several coins in it. The wallet had been open for a couple of hours so I don't know exactly when and how this problem began. All of a sudden, the wallet was showing a zero balance. The first thing I did was ***panic***. Then I decided to check the history. The history is intact and does not show any withdrawals today (nor should it). I stopped the daemon (it was fully synced), closed the wallet and re-opened it. No difference, still a zero balance. Can anyone tell me what likely happened and the best way to fix it (hopefully short of recreating it from seed)? Thanks very much.

PS- After reading another thread I decided to delete the wallet cache. Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the only way to trace what happen to your balance is through command line.

First, check if you are fully synchronized by typing the following command in the monerod.(The black window with many text showing)

> status

The next thing you can do is open the CLI wallet. It's the "monero-wallet-cli.exe"

Try running the following command

> rescan_bc

Also you can use the following command if there are transfers out/in

> show_transfers

Lastly, if all failed try deleting your blockchain(It is in C:\ProgramData\bitmonero) and synchronizing again using the latest monero here https://getmonero.org/home. Remember always backup your seed/keys before doing so.